# Understanding regex in java

Tags: java, regex

My program works how I want it to but I stumbled upon something that I don't understand.

```
String problem = "4 - 2";
problem = problem.replaceAll("[^-?+?0-9]+", " ");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(problem.trim().split(" ")));
```

prints `[4, -, 2]`

but

```
String problem = "4 - 2";
problem = problem.replaceAll("[^+?-?0-9]+", " ");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(problem.trim().split(" ")));
```

doesn't even do anything with the minus sign and prints `[4, 2]`

Why does it do that, it seems like both should work.

Comment: I've found regex debugging webapps like https://www.debuggex.com/ very useful.

Answer (score 3):

The hyphen has a special meaning inside a character class: it is used to define a character range (like `a-z` or `0-9`), except when:

- it is at the start of the character class or immediately after the negation character `^`
- it is escaped with a backslash
- it is at the end of the character class
- with some regex engines when it is after a shorthand character class like `\w`, `\s`, `\d`, `\p{thing}`,... *(for these one, the situation isn't ambiguous, it can't be a range)*

In the first example, it is seen as a literal hyphen (since it is at the beginning).

In your second example, I assume that `?-?` defines a range between `?` and `?` *(that is nothing more than the character `?`)*

Note: `?` doesn't have a special meaning inside a character class *(it's no more a quantifier but a simple literal character)*

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, `+?-?` means "a plus sign, or any chars between `?` and `?`, inclusive. Of course, that means just `?`, so the whole regex is equivalent to `[^+?0-9]+`.

The only time within a character class (between the square brackets) that `-` doesn't mean "between, inclusive" is at the start of the character class, or immediately following a `^` that starts it, or at the end of the character class, or when it's escaped (`\-`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to match a literal `-` inside of a `[` and `]`,  it must be escaped, `\-`. In the first case, ^ marks the beginning of a match, so really you are match `-?`, so there is nothing to escape. In the second case, it seems like you are matching `?-?`, which can cause the regular expression to function in a way you did not expect.

PS: To escape in Java, you need `\\` instead of `\`.